# How to unlock all hats in Sushi Party?

Tags: sushiparty.io

There's a game browser game that I've been playing for a while. It's called [Sushi Party](https://www.sushiparty.io/)
[image]

There are certain hats that seem unlockable no matter what I do. The hats I'm referring to are as follows:
[image]

No matter how many pokimon-type balls I gather, the result of opening them is the following:
[image]

Any suggestions if, by any chance, you have played this game before?

Comment: Some are probably event based - for example I bet that 2020 looking one you could only have unlocked during New Years earlier this year.